# remove Analysis service from a SQL 2014 cluster

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, clustering, ssas

Is it possible to uninstall Analysis service from a SQL 2014 cluster. I’ve seen that it cannot be done in 2008/12. I’m hoping that this maybe fixed now

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest **not removing it**. Why do you need to remove it? If you aren't going to use it anymore, I would just remove it as a cluster resource (and any dependencies), and then disable the service on each node. No need to uninstall anything except to save a tiny amount of disk space. IMHO, anyway.